# jQuery closest element with an attribute that contains a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML code that looks like this:

```
<tr id="nbContent_GR1">...</tr>
<tr id="nbContent_GR2">...</tr>
<tr id="nbContent_GR3">...</tr>
<tr id="nbContent_GR4">...</tr>
<tr id="nbContent_GR5">...</tr>
<tr id="nbContent_GR6">...</tr>
```

Within one of the rows, I want to traverse up the DOM to find the closest  element that has an ID attribute that starts with "nbContent_GR". So basically I want to be able to find the parent TR element without knowing its exact ID, just the first one that starts with "nbContent_GR". Is this possible? If so, how would I go about it?

BTW, I'm aware of the closest() and "contains" selectors, just not sure if contains can be used on attribute values or not.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand what you asked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just do:

```
tr = $(this).closest("[id^='nbContent_GR']");
```

that will traverse the DOM up until it finds a parent with ID starting with 'nbContent_GR'

Comment: Perfect, I knew there was a simple solution I was missing. :) I wasn't aware of the purpose of the "^". Gotta love learning something new.

Answer (score 3):

```
.closest('[id^="nbContent_GR"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

Two useful pages to look at:

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

I think you can combine these for a solution.

From within the TR, find the closest TR. Then use the 'starts with' selector to find an ID which starts with your required value.

E.g.:

```
$(this).closest("tr").parent().find("id^='nbContent_GR'");
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be late but for those of you who like me want it a bit different way, I figured out this way.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn-info', function() {
  var cardId = $(this).closest(".cardClass").attr("id");
  alert(cardId);
  console.log(cardId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div id="card1" class="cardClass">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"></button>
  </div>
  <div id="card2" class="cardClass">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"></button>
  </div>
  <div id="card3" class="cardClass">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"></button>
  </div>
  <div id="cardn" class="cardClass">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```